How many permutations do we obtain when we use a set of numbers and allow either positive or negative numbers to be used?
I have a set of positive number $1$ to $n$. I will be using $r=n$ elements, so my permutations are
$$
\frac{n!}{(n-r)!} = \frac{n!}{0!} = n! 
$$
However, I will also be using the negative values of my set. So I have to substitute in my original set from $1$ to $n$ elements with the negative values of the set. Each of these substitutions will add $n!$ permutations to my set of "permutations".
So, for instance, if I have as my set of numbers $\{1, \dots, 3\}$, my set of permutations will be
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix} 
\{1,2,3\}, &\{1,3,2\}, &\{2,1,3\}, 
&\{2,3,1\}, &\{3,1,2\}, &\{3,2,1\} \\
\{-1,2,3\}, &\{-1,3,2\}, &\{2,-1,3\}, 
&\{2,3,-1\}, &\{3,-1,2\}, &\{3,2,-1\} \\
\vdots &&&&{}\ddots & \vdots \\
\{-1,-2,-3\}, &&&&{}\cdots &\{-3,-2,-1\}
\end{matrix}\right\}. 
$$
The "substitutions" can also be seen as the sum of combinations of the "substituted" negatives. First I substitute $\{-1\}$, then $\{-2\}$, then $\{-3\}$, then $\{-1, -2\}$, then $\{-1, -3\}$, then $\{-2, -3\}$, and finally $\{-1, 2, -3\}$. As can be seen, we have $7$ combinations to substitute. When added to the original permutation and multiplied by the number of permutations, we arrive a total of $8 \cdot 6 = 48$ sets.
The total number of permutations is $2^n \cdot n!$
I have coded a process like the one described above and believe this to be correct.
My question is: Is this quantification correct? Can I look it up/find a generic formula which confirms my data?

This is correct, and these signed permutations form something called the hyperoctahedral group $B_n$ (symmetries of the "octahedron" in $n$-dimensions with vertices $(\pm 1, \pm 1, \dots, \pm 1)$.

Thanks for the prompt answer, @SammyBlack. Also for the nice re-formatting

Oh, I just realized that I described the hypercube in $n$-dimensions, which is the dual to the hyperoctahedron (a.k.a., cross polytope, orthoplex, etc.), so it still has the same symmetry group. The hyperoctahedron has $2n$ vertices on the coordinate axes at distance $1$, i.e., all coordinates $0$ except for one that is $\pm 1$.

There are $n!$ ways to choose a rearrangement of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Then, for each of the $n$ numbers, there is either a minus sign in front of that number, or not. Since there are $2$ choices for each number, there are $2\times \dots \times 2=2^n$ ways to choose the minus signs. The multiplication principle then implies that the number of ways to complete both tasks, choosing a permutation and then choosing minus signs, is $n!\times 2^n$, just as you wrote.
